# Total count without limit

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am doing paging using limit and offset:

```
       Test.query(function(q){
           q.where('testName', 'LIKE', '%test%')
            .orWhere('testNo', '1234')
            .limit(limit)
            .offset(offset);
       })
       .fetchAll()
```

How can I get the total count without the limit?

Comment: What do you mean by total count? Like how many items are in that table without a limit or?

Comment: @Datsik yes, total items without the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Model.count` i think following should work

```
var q = Test
    .where('testName', 'LIKE', '%test%') 
    .orWhere('testNo', '1234');

q.limit(limit)
    .offset(offset)
    .then(function(results){
         q.count('id').then(...)
    })
```

Comment: @Alvin what error do you get on server? 500 is on client right?

Comment: Anyway, I have reference to https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/435, thank you, I up-vote it.

Comment: Your method also make 2 queries to the database?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just one query. In some comments of the issue you mentioned they use 2 queries.